# Error with over() ´sp ´ package in R

Tags: r, sp

I have a df with spatial points that I've converted into a spatial object (dai18) and I want to select only the points that are inside a polygon (peri_A).

I think my coordinate system is incorrect, because it gives me only NA when I apply this command:

```
points_withinA <- over(dai18 , peri_A, fn = NULL)
```

These are the ways in which I've pre-treated the data:

```
dai18<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(dai18[,c("latitud","longitud")], data=dai18, 
                                  proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

peri_A <- readOGR("./centroH/Perimetro_A_region.shp", layer = ogrListLayers("./centroH/Perimetro_A_region.shp"))
peri_A<-spTransform(peri_A, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format.

Comment: What is proj4string(peri_A) telling you?

Comment: `> proj4string(dai18)
[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
> proj4string(peri_A)
[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
>`

Comment: Are you sure there are points within the polygon? Try plotting the polygon using `plot(peri_A)` and then run `points(dai18)` to verify that there is actually overlap.